# Dapper incorrectly thinking Column Numeric

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have been using dapper for a while but have come across a strange issue.

I have a Column in a database table called , in my query my Table

my dapper query is

`SELECT p.Id PaymentId, p.AmountPaid PaymentAmountPaid, np.NoticeNo PaymentRef`

In the Database the column NoticeNo is defined as nchar

When I query it, its mapped to class with the following property

```
public string PaymentRef { get; set; }
```

I query as follows `connection.Query<PaymentSummary>(sqlStr)`

but very strange, dapper seems to think that the NoticeNo column is a  number, so if the store notice no as **1234** then when its queried the result is ***1234.00***

Most of the notice numbers are numeric, but they don't have to be.

Any ideas?

Thanks ash.

Comment: There's not enough here to go on.  This is likely an issue with the DB or maybe the class you're mapping to.  Make sure the same sql query returns the correct values and maybe check your class for any weird formatting that it might be doing.

Comment: Not sure how much more I can tell you.  It seems that Dapper is inferring from the column name (***NoticeNo***) that the column is going to be numeric - but as I said its ***nchar***

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it wasn't Dapper's Fault.  The query was part of a union, and I had the notice no and the amount column in a different order in two if the queries, which was forcing the result to be a Number!!